# How to make a theme selector apply changes application wide

Tags: c#, wpf, themes

I am trying to make a togglebutton that will change the applications theme to being mobile-friendly when pressed. This is a special skin that only changes a few things like margins, font sizes, and minheights/widths. This should not remove the other styles I have set.

I was able to get the button to work, but the changes are only applying to the current window. How can I change this code to make it work on the entire application?

Searching around I have found that using "Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries" is probably the way to go, but I do not know how to incorporate it.

The information from this website is the foundation.
http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.com/2009/07/switching-wpf-interface-themes-at.html

Here is the code for the theme selector.

```
public class ThemeSelector : DependencyObject
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentThemeDictionaryProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CurrentThemeDictionary", typeof(Uri),
        typeof(ThemeSelector),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, CurrentThemeDictionaryChanged));

    public static Uri GetCurrentThemeDictionary(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Uri)obj.GetValue(CurrentThemeDictionaryProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCurrentThemeDictionary(DependencyObject obj, Uri value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CurrentThemeDictionaryProperty, value);
    }

    private static void CurrentThemeDictionaryChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (obj is FrameworkElement) // works only on FrameworkElement objects
        {
            ApplyTheme(obj as FrameworkElement, GetCurrentThemeDictionary(obj));
        }
    }

    private static void ApplyTheme(FrameworkElement targetElement, Uri dictionaryUri)
    {
        if (targetElement == null) return;

        try
        {
            ThemeResourceDictionary themeDictionary = null;
            if (dictionaryUri != null)
            {
                themeDictionary = new ThemeResourceDictionary();
                themeDictionary.Source = dictionaryUri;

                // add the new dictionary to the collection of merged dictionaries of the target object
                targetElement.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Insert(0, themeDictionary);
            }

            // find if the target element already has a theme applied
            List<ThemeResourceDictionary> existingDictionaries =
                (from dictionary in targetElement.Resources.MergedDictionaries.OfType<ThemeResourceDictionary>()
                 select dictionary).ToList();

            // remove the existing dictionaries 
            foreach (ThemeResourceDictionary thDictionary in existingDictionaries)
            {
                if (themeDictionary == thDictionary) continue;  // don't remove the newly added dictionary
                targetElement.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(thDictionary);
            }
        }
        finally { }
    }
}
```

Here is the stuff in the code-behind for the togglebutton.

```
    private void MobileTheme_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked.Value)
        {
            ThemeSelector.SetCurrentThemeDictionary(this, new Uri("/MobileSkin.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            ThemeSelector.SetCurrentThemeDictionary(this, new Uri("/ClassicSkin.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New code that works:

```
public class ThemeSelector : DependencyObject
{
    public static void ApplyTheme(Uri dictionaryUri)
    {
        var targetElement = Application.Current;
        if (targetElement == null || dictionaryUri == null) return;

        try
        {
            // find if the target element already has a theme applied
            var existingDictionaries =
                (from dictionary in targetElement.Resources.MergedDictionaries.OfType<ThemeResourceDictionary>()
                 select dictionary).ToList();

            // remove the existing dictionaries 
            foreach (var thDictionary in existingDictionaries)
            {
                targetElement.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(thDictionary);
            }

            // add the new dictionary to the collection of merged dictionaries of the target object, needs to be added to the end to overwrite the other items
            targetElement.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ThemeResourceDictionary { Source = dictionaryUri });
        }
        finally { }
    }
}
```

Toggle button:

```
    private void MobileTheme_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as ToggleButton)?.IsChecked.Value == true)
        {
            ThemeSelector.ApplyTheme(new Uri("/MobileSkin.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            ThemeSelector.ApplyTheme(new Uri("/ClassicSkin.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```